# DataGridView is Bind But Not displayed

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, gridview

I am making Winforms application. I have put gridview in usercontrol. Which is another control.

```
public long FileID
    {
        get { return _FileID; }
        set 
        {
            _FileID =value;
            BindGridView();
        }
    }
```

Here I am setting property values and binding gridview , I am getting records in Messagebox too, but I cant find Gridview. Help me. Thanks.

```
private void BindGridView()
         {
             if (_FileID!= 0)
             {
                 srHstyFiles = new dms_client.History_Files.History_FilesSoapClient();
                 DataTable dt;
                 dt = srHstyFiles.GetHistoryRevisionfile(_FileID);
                 gvHstoryRev.DataSource = dt;
                 gvHstoryRev.Refresh();
                 gvHstoryRev.Parent.Refresh();
                 MessageBox.Show(gvHstoryRev[1,2].values.tostring());
             }
         }
```

Comment: Make sure you have defined column names at design time or set AutoGeneratedColumns property to true in code.

Comment: i am using Autogeneratecolumn=True property.

Comment: How and where are you assigning this property ?

Comment: gvHstoryRev.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
gvHstoryRev.DataSource = dt;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have drag and drop user control and you are making  new object and try to set property then your grid view wouldn't bind any way.
 
When ever user control dropped c# generate automatic instance of user control of its name.

**Example**
ParentControl.ChildControl.FileID = id;